# Aligning text in nodes and format issues

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, formatting

How  can I manage it, that I. and II. are horizontally aligned in the middle of the box!? Furthermore I want the text (gray box) in bold but \textbf does not work!?

Thank you!

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}

    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                                         
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                                            
    \usepackage[english,german,ngerman]{babel}                                          
    \usepackage{lmodern}                                                                
    \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}       
    \usepackage{microtype}                                                              
    \usepackage{ragged2e}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \newcommand{\tabitem}{~~\llap{\textbullet}~~}                                       
    \newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{2}{p{\dimexpr0.85\linewidth-3\tabcolsep\relax}}{#1}}
    \usepackage{array}
    %\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}                                                    
    \usepackage{enumitem}

    \usepackage{fp}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{xcolor}
    \usetikzlibrary{positioning,shadings}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.shapes}
    \usetikzlibrary{decorations.text}
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}   
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

    \usepackage[babel,german=quotes]{csquotes}                                      
    \usepackage[language=autobib]{biblatex}
    %\usepackage[language=autobib,backend=biber]{biblatex}


    \begin{document}
    \begin{center}
    \scalebox{0.6}{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm, transform shape]

    \node[name=c,anchor=north] at (2,-1.5) {};

    \node [name=d, anchor=north, draw=black!80, text centered, text width=4.5cm, minimum height = 8cm, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, fill=gray!0] at ($(c.south)+(-10.6,-0.04)$) {\textbf{I. text text text} \\(text)};

    \node [name=e, anchor=north,  draw=black!80, text centered, text width=4.5cm, minimum height = 8cm, rectangle, rounded corners=1mm, fill=gray!0] at ($(c.south)+(-4.5375,-0.04)$) {\textbf{II. text text text} \\(text text text text text text text text text)};

    \node [name=f, anchor=north, draw, text width=8.6cm, align=center, rectangle, minimum height = 1.25cm, rounded corners=0mm, fill=gray!95] at ($(d.south)+(+0.25,0)$) {\textcolor{white}{this text in bold???}};


    \end{tikzpicture}}
    \end{center}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: You can add `text=white, font=\bfseries` to the options of the gray node and remove the `\textcolor` command. For your other question, the text is already horizontally centered right?

Comment: This should also work: `\textbf{\textcolor{white}{this text in bold???}}`

Comment: With horizontal alignment I meant that (I.) and (II.) are in one line (now (I.) ist below (II.)).

Answer (score 1):

- for mwe your preamble is not minimal. the most of packages and libraies are not related to your problem
- i would not use `\scalebox` for reduce image size. rather define nodes styles and there determine  size of shapes
- in nodes positioning i would use `tikz` library `positioning` and its synax. with `node distance = <vertical> and <horisontal>` i would determine vertical and horizontal distance between node (your approach is not wrong, however is to complicated to my opinion)

  ```
  \documentclass[a4paper]{scrbook}
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} it is contained in recent version of latex
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
  \usepackage[english,german,ngerman]{babel}
  \usepackage{textcomp}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage}
  \usepackage{microtype}
  \usepackage{xcolor}
  \usepackage{tikz}
  \usetikzlibrary{positioning}


  \begin{document}
  \begin{center}
      \begin{tikzpicture}[
  node distance = 0mm and 20mm,
     box/.style = {draw=black!80, rounded corners,
                   text width=30mm, minimum height=50mm, align=center},
    gbox/.style = {box, fill=#1, text width=50mm, minimum height=12mm,
                   font=\bfseries, text=white},
                           ]
  \node [name=d, box]             {\textbf{I. text text text} \\(text)};
  \node [name=e, box, right=of d] {\textbf{II. text text text} \\
                                   (text text text text text text text text text)};
  \node [name=f, gbox,
         below=of d ]             {\textcolor{white}{this text in bold???}};
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{center}
  \end{document}
  ```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your comments. This is just part of a larger picture, where I had to adjust a lot of things. Nevertheless I will use the positioning for "more simple" graphics.

Comment: instead saying "thank you" you could up-vote my answer and even accepting it :-)